# Probability of clearing a multiple choice exam

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A student faces a multiple choice exam with $50$ questions, each question has four choices with one correct answer. What is the chance to prevail by pure luck? Half of the answers must be correct.

I begin with the two question case. I'm assuming the questions are blank dot columns and that the correct exam paper has the top row filled out in black. One correct answer is enough. There are $16$ ways to fill out the exam paper, $7$ ways are correct. The chance to prevail is $7/16$.

Generalizing this to the $n$ question case, there are $$\frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2)!}\cdot(4^{(n/2)}-1)+1$$

correct ways to fill out the exam paper. If there are $50$ questions, the chance to prevail is $$\frac{1.42325\cdot10^{29}}{4^{50}}=0.11227$$

But certainly this number is way too large? Methinks the logic used in the two question case is not entirely correct is it?

Comment: The number of correct solutions , let us call it $X$ , is a random variable binomial distributed with parameters $n=50$ and $p=0.25$. The desired probability is $P(X\ge 25)\approx 0.00012251$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the $i$th question, with $X_i = 1$ if you get the question correct and $0$ otherwise.

With a pure guess you have $p = 0.25$ chance of getting it right. So this is Bernoulli with probability $0.25$

Now what we are looking for is $P(X_1 + \cdots + X_{50} \geq 25)$.

The key observation is that **the sum of bernoulli dists is a binomial distribution**.

So the total marks $Y = \sum_{1\leq i\leq50} X_i$ is binomial with $50$ trials and probability of success $p = 0.25$. With this information alone you can exactly calculate the probability as

$P(Y \geq 25) = P(Y = 25) + P(Y=26) + ... + P(Y=50) = {50 \choose 25}0.25^{25}0.75^{25} + {50 \choose 26}0.25^{26}0.75^{24} + ... + {50 \choose 50}0.25^{50}0.75^0$

There are online calculators that do this for you. [Stattrek](https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial) tells me that the answer is $0.00012$